# My Blazor UI is not responding on a domain, but working on another domain

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, cloudflare, .net-8.0

I have a blazor app that's running on container. Seems to have an issue on domain level because on Domain A it's working but on Domain B it's not. WebSocket is allowed on both domains as per checking on the console.

Domain A: I can see this on the network of my devtools for Domain A

[image: Blazor WebSocket request on Network devtools]

but not on Domain B. No other error messages displayed on the console as well.

Is there a way for blazor to not use websocket?
I'm not using WASM btw, my rendermode is Interactive SSR

Update 1: seems like it became a static application. The Async tasks attached on the buttons seems not being triggered.

Update 2: We were able to make the the blazor app work only when the Devmode of the domain is enabled. Devmode

Comment: SignalR should fall back on long polling. I think you have some other (configuration) problem.